# Unable to built samba 4.10.6 from source

Tags: samba

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installed at my home desktop.

I want to be able to backup my Mac laptop using time machine in Ubuntu hard drives. For this purpose, I need samba 4.8.0 or later, which I have to install from source.

I followed [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/samba.html) link for installing the latest samba-4.10.6.

I've created an environment with Python 3.4.
It configured without problems, however, on make step there is an error:

```
 /home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `tgetstr'

/home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `tputs'

/home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `BC'

/home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `tgetent'

/home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `tgetflag'

/home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `tgoto'

/home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `UP'

/home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `tgetnum'

/home/misha/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libreadline.so: undefined 
reference to `PC'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Waf: Leaving directory `/home/misha/Downloads/samba-4.10.6/bin/default'

Build failed

 -> task in 'smbtorture' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to 
display more information)

Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Did anyone had a problem with this? I was not able to solve it.

Thanks,
Misha

Comment: I don't see any mention of Anaconda (or even python3) in the instructions you linked - why exactly are you using a python3.4 environment / toolchain here?

Comment: @steeldriver I use anaconda for python version management. It did not configure with Python 3.7, so I tried Python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a lot of work here:

1. exclude Anaconda from this compilation by setting usual PATH variable

   `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`
2. get all needed build-dependencies from repository with

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep samba
   ```
3. compile source to binary deb-package [with `sudo checkinstall make install`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package)
4. install resulting deb-package.

---

But I'll recommend to save CPU power and time while using binary package from PPA [`ppa:linux-schools/samba-latest`](https://launchpad.net/~linux-schools/+archive/ubuntu/samba-latest?field.series_filter=bionic).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linux-schools/samba-latest
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install samba
```

And if you want to revert to previous Samba version - use the following commands to purge PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:linux-schools/samba-latest
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!